# Cloud Pages: 404 not found

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I am building a custom preference center using cloud pages.

I am also using a custom link and appending different abbreviations to the it to create localised content for different regions.

Once copied, the links return a

> 404 error

I have whitelisted these link on the internal fire wall and cant seem to figure this out on my  own.

Comment: Could you write here the code ampscript if you are using any functions in this cloud page?

Comment: It's almost certainly an error in the code itself, as opposed to firewall related. Unfortunately CloudPage errors are less informative than their Landing Pages predecessor.

Comment: If you are using personalised URL about using a backslash in variable name of the URL. You can use "_" instead.

Comment: Was a rooky error. I had not published the page.